# Ruby on Rails: How to display posts on a static home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a Rails app and what I'm trying to do is show all the posts on the homepage. I have a controller for static pages that's where the homepage comes from and another controller for posts. So far I have this:

**home.html.erb**:

```html
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.comment %>
<% end %>
```

**Posts controller**:

```
def home 
 @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(5)
end
```

I get the general idea from looking at other answers but I still get an `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error even though I have more than one post in the database.

So far communities have many posts if that relationship affects it at all. 
Thanks.

**Static pages controller**:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: which line number you are getting this error. Can you post the development.log with error details

Comment: How does your static pages controller look like?

Comment: class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def show
  render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
    end

end

Comment: Please share backtrace of error from server log in question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there would be nothing to tell your `StaticController` to execute the `home` action which you have in the `PostsController`.

Vishal is correct in that you should probably move the logic into the `StaticController`, however there is still nothing to call that action.

A solution would be to instantiate `@posts` in your `#index` route so that when someone visits the index, that logic is executed.

The better solution, in my opinion, would be to make `#home` a private method in your `StaticController` (maybe rename it to something more descriptive... I used `load_posts` below), and then at the top of the file create a `before_action` to tell Rails that you want the contents of `#load_posts` when rendering the `index`

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_posts, only: :index

  def index
    #logic for your index
  end

  private

  def load_posts
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(5)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just put your code `@posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(5)` into that static pages controller? `PostsController` doesn't render `home.erb.html` by default, it has its own views.

Comment: I have tried that as well (I put it in a posts module) but to no avail, I'm honestly stumped as to what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that there is static controller from where the home page is coming, then I am not sure, why you are creating different action for home, in `Posts Controller`. Place your home action in static controller.

**StaticController**

```
def home 
 @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(5)
end
```

Comment: I've tried this now, but it still gives me the exact same error. Is there anything else you can think of? I'm quite new to rails so I don't know what else I can try.

Comment: As per my advice on [chatty questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49627892), there's no need to add "hope this helps" to all of your answers. All posters hope their material helps, and it is not necessary in technical writing.